# Determine whether a piecewise function is injective or surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have the following piecewise function, and I want to determine if it is injective or surjective (or both) and then calculate the inverse.
$$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x^2 - 2, & \text{if } x \gt 0,\\
      x-1, & \text{if } x \leq 0.
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

I have watched videos and read a couple of questions on here, but I cannot find a clear answer. For injectivity, one suggested going through each case and checking that if $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$

**Case 1: $x,y > 0$**

$x^2 - 2 = y^2 - 2$

Clearly, $x = y$

**Case 2: $x,y \leq 0$**

The same as above applies for this case. $x-1 = y-1$

What if $x > 0 \text{ and } y \leq 0\text{?}$

And how should I check if this function is surjective?

Comment: Did you try drawing a graph first? That might help give you an idea of what the answer is at least. Once you're fairly certain about the answer, you can then go about proving it. I would recommend doing that for this question.

Comment: First define your domain of the function $f$ at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>0$ and $y\leq 0$, then obviously $x\neq y$. So if we can find $x>0$ and $y\leq 0$, such that $f(x)=f(y)$, we've shown $f$ is not injective. Consider:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=f(y)\\
x^2-2&=y-1\\
x^2&=y+1\\
x&=\sqrt{y+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
What would now be a constriction on $y$ for this equation to hold? And what can you conclude then about injectivity?

As far as surjectivity goes: check the surjectivity in cases too, and then decide on the "total" surjectivity. I will show you how to do this for $x>0$:

We know that for $x>0$, we have that $f(x)=x^2-2$. Now I don't know how rigorous you want this to be, but I would think it's fine to immediately state that $f(x)$ covers $(-2,\infty)$, for $x>0$. You can do the same for $x\leq 0$, and then conclude on surjectivity by considering the union of both sets.

*edit*

I realised that checking surjectivity could have be done a little bit more rigorously, so I will show that too:

Let $y\in\mathbb R$. If $y\in(-\infty,-1]$, then for $x=y+1$, $f(x)=x-1=y$. If $y\in(-1,\infty)$, then for $x=\sqrt{y+2}$, $f(x)=x^2-2=y$. Hence, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I think the restriction would be $y > - 1$? If $y = 0 \implies x=1$ and this would mean $f(x) \ne f(y)$. So it is not injective

Comment: Correct! A little bit more precise: $y\geq-1$ and $y\leq 0$ (our first assumption!), so the restriction is: $y\in[-1,0]$. This does not mean $f(x)\neq f(y)$, in fact, it means that $f(x)=f(y)$ while $x\neq y$. Your conclusion is right.

Comment: If you're keen on using logical symbols:
$$
\forall x>0,\exists y\in[-1,0]:f(x)=f(y).
$$
You have to realise that it is $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x\neq y$, and *not* $f(x)\neq f(y)$!
(edit; lol, now it looks like I'm overdoing it with this message, but it was a response to your deleted comment:P)

Comment: Sorry yes I realised my comment was basically restating what you wrote, so I tried to delete it so I didn't waste your time :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! How would I go about the cases for surjectivity? I have so far: if $x, y > 0$ 
$f(x) = x^2 -2, \exists n : n = x^2 -2 \implies x = \sqrt{n+2}$ iff $f$ is surjective

Comment: I'll edit my previous response as regards to surjectivity!

Comment: You are very good at explaining things! It actually makes sense now! For $x \le 0, f(x) = x - 2 \implies f(x) \in [-\infty, -2]$ So in conclusion, $[\infty, -2) \cup(-2, +\infty] = [-\infty, +\infty]$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Cobbled Yes, it is!:) Please be aware of the convention that we use round brackets for infinity, because a function can never have $\pm\infty$ as its value! So the more "conventionally correct" answer would be: $(-\infty,\infty)$. Glad to have helped!

Comment: That is good to know, thank you :)